# How to print List's object elements in Java?

Tags: java, list, object, linked-list, println

I have something like the following:

```
List<Interval> intervals = new LinkedList<Interval>();
intervals.add(new Interval(1));
intervals.add(new Interval(2));
```

How can I print the List `intervals`? I attempted `System.out.println(intervals)`, but it simply returns `[Interval@...]`.

Thank you

Comment: `for (Interval ival : intervals) { System.out.println(ival.name()); }` ... this must be a duplicate of something

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not in printing the `List` but in printing the `Interval`.

Implement `Interval.toString()` method.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println(intervals)` will call `.toString()` method of the object you are trying to print, which is List.

In order to print every object you have to override the `toString()` method for `Interval` or print specific value.

`for (Inteval interval : intervals) { System.out.println(interval.getValue());}`

or if you override the `toString()` method for Interval

`for (Inteval interval : intervals) { System.out.println(interval);}`

You can override the `toString()` as follows:

```
public class Interval {
    public int value;
    public String val; 

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Value string: " + val + " value int: " + value;
    }
}
```